# App be killed in the background running in iOS 7

Tags: ios, background, ios7

My app uses CoreBluetooth to connect a BLE device, also adds the UIBackgroundModes (the value "bluetooth-central") in the info.plist. When the app into the background, app can continue to read the RSSI Value from a connected device. But app be killed in the background every time after several minutes. I uses instruments tool to test the live bytes, the total bytes about 12MB. Test the app in iphone4s,iphone5,iphone5s, there are such problems. So I don't know how to resolve it? My app requires the long time running in the background. Everyone has other ideas?

Comment: You app could be killed by another one, the background mode doesn't guarantee that your app would not be killed. If the system claims some memory, first it kills the "other", if it needs memory again it kills also background applications. On which devices are you testing it, and what kind of operations are you doing after closing the app?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start a background task.

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier taskIdentifier = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    // Cleanup before closing app
}];
```

Comment: This is useful for expiring tasks, not for full background support mode.